# SSL Website showing 404 error over non-SSL (HTTP)

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I've set up an SSL site on server 2012 using CCS and SNI. When attempting to navigate to it over a non-SSL link (http), the site throws a 404 error.

How can I get it to show the "This site requires SSL" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add HTTP to your bindings in IIS.

Instead of showing "This site requires SSL" you should redirect your user to the equivalent SSL page (e.g. `http://twitter.com/about` would redirect to `https://twitter.com/about`).

It is bad for both end-users and SEO to display a message with a message asking the user to change the URL. If you look at different websites on the Web you can notice that this is automatic and doesn't require any action from the user.

Comment: Ok, I get that and that's what we'll end up doing. But still, how would I get the site to display the message about requiring SSL?

Comment: Oh wait, did I miss it? "You need to add HTTP to your bindings in IIS." I did that using port 80, and it didn't work....

Comment: If you added the 2 bindings on correct ports that should work. If you still get error 404 in theory your HTTP binding should be wrong (or you have another redirection pointing to a not found page)