# SSL certificate is installed on iis and website but in browser is unknown

Tags: .net, iis, cert

I have WebApi project in .net 3.1 that i deploy it on IIS
And i creat self-signed certificate  on IIS

[image: Image from IIS]
[image: There is my biding to defalt web site]

When i browse to the defalt website i get that the site is secure:
[image]

But when i browse to the appliction i get that the site is not secure:
[image]

What could cause the problem?

I try to have permissions to my appliction by add iis_iusrs
And i expect to receive secure access (ssl cert) when accessing my application

Comment: https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics# Secure or not the report can tell you more.

Comment: Well it isn't secure, it's got a self-signed certificate. Self-signed is not secure at all, and may as well not use any encryption. Anyone can self-sign, what's the point of it? Also your actual problem is a 404 error, so your app isn;t even being called. And why .NET 3.1 that's waaay out of date?

Comment: Self-signed certificates are not trusted by browsers by default. You need to install the certificate manually in your browser or add it to the list of trusted root certification authorities (CA). But now the HTTP ERROR 404 is the key problem you need to solve. Please provide detailed error information.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have not [setup binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding) or it is not set up correctly. It's hard to be more specific with just the information you have shown in screenshots here.

Also, the screenshot where you show the ssl cert is not showing is also giving you a 404 error. Have you tested with another app page that is working?

Further reading:

- Another [post with an issue of IIS binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18242335/23663817)
- [Official Microsoft documentation for IIS binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/bindings/)